# UITabBarController Hide Show Bars with animation like the Photo APP

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, hide, show

i'm having a real trouble with UITabBarController. I have a simple foto app, and I'm trying to simulate almost the same behaviour as the PhotoApp from the Iphone
the main view controler is the tabbar itself, i also have a NavBar and a status bar on top.

What i want is on tap to hide the bars (not with timer, just on tap).
The photo is actually an UIScroll view that zooms the photo or makes it again 1:1. that part already works,

I've tried before pushing the view to the navbar to set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed and well it works, but i can't set a custom animation, and that's not the real problem , I can't show again the bars, they dissapear and i don't know how to reshow them, i'm sure i'm probably missing someting very obvious, but as my experience in obj C is little like half a year part time, i thought i asked here as stackoverflow seems to get the answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to investigate: the Three20 project: http://github.com/facebook/three20 - it includes a completely clone of the photo-browsing app in component form.

But without Three20, you can't do this with a stock `UINavigationController`, because the `UIViewController` that you're using is a subview of the `UINavigationController`. You need to make a sibling view on another layer. To do this, make a parent `UIViewController` which has two subviews: your photo, and a UIToolbar. You can hide and display the UIToolbar by setting it's `hidden` property, and make sure it's above the photo view with `[parent.view bringSubviewToFront:toolbarController]` (where `parent` is the main UIViewController that contains both the photo view and the `UIToolbar`)

Comment: Just to add something about the animation: Many changes to UIViews can be animated very easily just by putting the changes between calls to beginAnimations:: and commitAnimations. See This: http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW62